# Why are the cookies behaving oddly when the website is hosted on GoDaddy?

Tags: c#, cookies

I am using cookies for user login in a website. The login page has simply two textboxes (textbox9 as email id and textbox10 as password). The bode behind of the login button click is as follows:-

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from stud where emaili='" + TextBox9.Text + "'", con);
    con.Close();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        Label3.Text = "unknown user";
    else if (dt.Rows[0][8].ToString() == TextBox9.Text && dt.Rows[0][3].ToString()==TextBox10.Text)
        {
            Label3.Text = "login success";
            Response.Cookies["stdId"].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("stdPortal.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Text = "invalid login";

        }

}
```

The user's landing page(stdportal.aspx)'s page load event's code behind is as follows, where I read the cookie:-

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
DataTable dt_stud = new DataTable();
DataTable dt_query = new DataTable();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
public void create_table()
{
    DataColumn col;
    col = new DataColumn();
    col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    col.ColumnName = "query";
    dt_query.Columns.Add(col);

    col = new DataColumn();
    col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    col.ColumnName = "resolved";
    dt_query.Columns.Add(col);
}
int std_id;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    create_table();
    if (Request.Cookies["stdId"] != null)
    {
        std_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["stdId"].Value);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda_stud = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from stud where id='" + std_id + "'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda_query = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from query where std_id='" + std_id + "'", conn);
        conn.Close();

        sda_query.Fill(dt);
        sda_stud.Fill(dt_stud);
        Label1.Text = "Welcome " + dt_stud.Rows[0][1].ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt_query.NewRow();
            row["query"] = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();

            row["resolved"] = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();
            dt_query.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt_query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");

}
```

These work fine when I run the site from localhost, but when hosted on GoDaddy, I get these odd behaviors:-
1) I login with a registered email and correct password but it shows "invalid login" which is set if password doesn't match
2) After the above action if I login with the same id and leave the password field blank, I can login successfully and my name is correctly shown in the landing page
3) Then if I to back to the login page and login keeping both email id and password field blank I login as a different user

Am I using the cookies wrongly? If so, where am I wrong?

Comment: Setting aside your cookie question, there are some *major* problems with this code.  You should read up on SQL Injection attacks (basically this code will allow anybody to remotely get any info they want out of your data, modify your database, or even delete it all.  You should also read up on the user login stuff that is built into .NET rather than building your own from scratch.

Comment: Further, keep in mind that cookies are not inherently secure - a user can easily edit their cookies which would let them (based on your code here) access the data belonging to other students.  Cookies should encrypted by the server if you want to store tamper-proof information in them